# Chrome Extension suddenly does not work: Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension

as a beginner, I am making a chrome plugin with javascript which simply simulates a button click on a web page. Weirdly, it worked for me just now and after closing and opening chrome again, I constantly get the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" for content.js (line 16).

**Here are my codes:**

popup.html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Set Page Color Popup</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button1">New Facet</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```js
function start_js()
 {
 chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"});
 });
 }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', start_js);
 });
```

content.js:

```js
function startup(){
 document.getElementById("buttonAdd").children[0].click();
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.greeting == "hello"){
    startup();
  } 
 }
);
```

Can you help me to find a solution? Thanks so much in advance!

Best,
Max

Comment: content.js in the question doesn't have 16 lines.

Comment: Here, line 16 is the } (third last) of content.js:

Comment: Without seeing the actual file it's impossible to guess just by one line.